# How to modify graph or node display settings in browser?

Tags: graph

This might be a basic question.  I am http://localhost:7474/browser/ looking at sample graph.  How do I modify the graph settings?  Tried clicking on it but no side window showing up!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one here can see whatever page you are rendering on your local machine. We have no idea what this graph is, what tools were used to create it, or what the "settings" or "side window" you are expecting to see might be. You'll need to provide more information to receive a useful answer.

Comment: @Jonah: to me it sounds like OP tries to adjust an application setting without having written the app himself. So it's not on topic for Stack Overflow ([help/on-topic]).